# Twitter API 1.1 does not giving correct time

Tags: php, twitter

I am working on Twitter API 1.1. I want to fetch tweets from twitter for particular search. Here is my code :-

```
<?php

  date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');

  include "library/twitteroauth.php";

$consumerkey = "MY_CONSUMER _KEY";
$consumersecret = "CONSUMER_SECRET_KEY";
$accesstoken = "ACCESS_TOKEN";
$accesstokensecret = "ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET";

$twitter = new TwitterOAuth($consumerkey, $consumersecret, $accesstoken, $accesstokensecret);

/* FOR PARTICULAR SEARCH */

$tweets = $twitter -> get('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q='.$_POST['keyword']. '&img->tr&result_type=recent&count=50&until=2013-12-15'); //$_POST['keyword'] is a search text e.g. king

    foreach($tweets as $tweet){

       foreach($tweet as $t){

        $tweet_time = date("l M j \- g:ia",strtotime($t->created_at));

        echo 'Time----->'.date("l M j \- g:ia",strtotime($t->created_at));  


        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($t); 
?>
```

All works fine, all tweets comes successfully but the tweet time is not correct. Please see the screenshot below :-

[image]

How can I get the actual time of tweet from twitter. My timezone is Asia/Calcutta - India

Comment: I believe the "created_at" field is in UTC. Your application logic should read that data and convert it to display in your current locale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tweets from the rest API are always returned as the UTC time when the Tweet was created. [See the Twitter documentation for this here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/platform-objects/tweets)

Your application would need to read that date/time and convert it into your current timezone. To do this in PHP, have a look at php's inbuilt functions like [date](http://php.net/date), and [strtotime](http://www.php.net/strtotime), remembering you need to add or subtract a certain amount of hours depending on your own timezone.